# Drupal Quiz Module - emailing results after taking the quiz

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I have a Drupal website that uses the Quiz module to administer tests to visitors. These tests need to be available to anonymous users. My problem is that I need to be able to ask the test taker to enter name and e-mail so the results can be sent to them. I just don't know how to go about doing this. I consider myself a beginner in Drupal and PHP.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What Drupal version are you using? I presume Drupal 6 because the stable version of this module is only out for version six.

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7. Is there such an option in the stable version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-First of all, create a [custom module](http://drupal.org/developing/modules).

-Secondly, you need to add the email address and name fields. You can do this by either adding the two fields via [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) in your custom module or by enabling and using the Short Answer module/field that's included in your Quiz module and then customising the style of the field according to your needs (because it'll look like a question). Personally, I would recommend adding them using hook_form_alter. Plus, I suggest you learn about [Hooks](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/group/hooks/6) in Drupal, it will make your life easier.

-You have to validate and retrieve the values for the two fields. You can also use the same form_alter hook for this. [Add a validation and a submission function](http://zgadzaj.com/how-to-add-your-own-extra-validate-or-submit-function-using-drupals-hookformalter) to the validate and the submit stack of your Quiz form (`$form['#validate'][] = 'your_validate_function';` and `$form['#submit'][] = 'your_submit_function';`). You can validate your email by using Drupal's function [valid_email_address](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/valid_email_address/6) and, of course, you can validate other fields and calling Drupal's [form_set_error](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_error/6) to notify users of any input mistakes.

-To send your email after the Quiz is submitted, call Drupal's drupal_mail, in your submit function, which basically takes all the parameters needed to send an email. You'll have to create a hook_mail in your custom module. Check out an example of how to do this [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/6). You can retrieve your form values (name and email address) from the local array $form_state['values'], pass them as $params to your drupal_mail function and add them to the body of your email in your hook_mail function. And that's it :D

-Alternatively, you can send an email by creating an action and assigning an action to be performed after a user has completed this Quiz. The Quiz module has support for that. Here's an example of [how to write an action](http://www.sysarchitects.com/node/47).

Comment: wow, thank you so much!
I will try this out. Hopefully I will make it somewhere!

Answer (score 1):

You may also use `hook_quiz_finished` instead of form submit callback.
Quiz module uses it to perform actions like sending results over email at the end of a quiz.

```
function mymodule_quiz_finished($quiz, $score, $session_data) {
  //Sending e-mail.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ended here and you are using Drupal 7, go to Rules http://www.yourwebsite.com/admin/config/workflow/rules, and set the rule that the Quiz module has made available already to active under the settings, the rule is called "Send quiz results at the end of a quiz". I couldn't find the ability to do this anywhere within the Quiz config itself. Tested and its working. Be sure that the Rules Module UI is enabled to allow you to make the edits.